# Right to left in QToolBox

Tags: qt, qt5, right-to-left, qt5.3

I add a `QToolBox` to my ui file.

But there is no any option to change alignment!

I want change `QToolBox` header text alignment from left to right to right to left.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no any magic method which change the alignment, but you can use stylesshets. For example:

```
ui->toolBox->setStyleSheet(" QToolBox::tab {padding-left: 10px;} ");
```

This code allows you move text of header to right and to left(if you reset this option), but it isn't alignment. Anyways it is better than nothing.